# Tips for client server communication for website with loads of images

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs, frameworks

I want to build comic book reading website that it has thousands of images on the server. Each series has hundreds of chapters and each chapter has tens of images.
So I want to display these images on my website. How can we do this with less effort?

I am using AngularJS for the frontend, and for the API its Slim Framework.

I read that storing the img paths on the database is better solution. So its good to query all the image paths to MYSQL? Like `http://mywebsite.com/mangas/naruto/23/001.jpg`. Or use some sort of regular expression. But every image has different extensions. Some of it `.png`, some of it`.jpg` and some of it 3 digits naming, some of it 2 digits naming.

-And what about when I upload a new chapter. Do I have to query all the images again?

-So is there a solution for me like this: I upload chapter wtih SFTP and then automatically my website updates itself and the chapter I uploaded appear on my website. Is somemthing like this achievable?

Comment: Your question is far too broad and cannot be answered comprehensively. You should do some initial research online and come back with some more specific questions.

Comment: There are two ways to go about it. First, traditional way, is to have a CMS for managing data. You upload files trough forms, and your backend sorts them, and stores the data in the database. Second way would be without a CMS, but then you'd need to manually organize files and folders via FTP. The backend would just read a list of files and send them to the front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So many many ways to do this.

How about putting all the images for one chapter, in a CSV file stored
on your server; so, one file for each chapter... then, request a chapter.

Slim gets the httpRequest and fires a quick php read of the file; put each
line into an array, inside a for loop.  Then, to make it easier on the client side, the array before Slim returns the data.

Then on client, each element of the array will be the name of one of 
the images for the chapter the user is viewing/reading; feed the image
names into your Angular...

Just take a deep breath and build something, then figure out how to make it better.